# How can I get signal data during simulation from a Simulink model and pass it to a GUI (born in GUIDE)?

Tags: matlab-figure, simulink, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to move a slider with the signal data change or just simply show the numbers in a text box. Can somebody hit me with some tips to achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance!
Norbert

Comment: See http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/06/01/use-matlab-guis-with-simulink-models/

Comment: Thank you!
I already have a pupulated GUI which uses SET_PARAM_API (to control some Gain blocks and manual switches). 
If I implement a Level-2 S-Function to my model can I send the data to the existing GUI, or this way has the possibility to result unexpected behaviour? (Sorry, I'm newby.)

Comment: Assuming the S-Function knows about the UI handle that it needs, then yes it can write to the UI.  You will however need to worry about issues such as "what if the UI has been closed by the user"?